# How do I get rid of the default "index" Header that shows up on my react native app

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

Here is the code I have:

```
`import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>This is the header text</Text>
            <Text>Hello World</Text>
            <Text>Is this under? Yes it is</Text>
        </View>
    
);
}

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: "dodgerblue",
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
        },
        headerText: {
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            marginBottom: 10,
          },
    });`
```

I tried to hide the header and make it false, using the stack navigation already but that did not work. I also tried the topbar method. Here is how it looks like,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDuxe.png)